# RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (59) : device-side assert triggered a

Tags: cuda

I checked other suggestions, but other people used RNN Networks and data labels.
In my case, everything was working fine yesterday, but suddenly my code is not working anymore.

I am trying to run this python code on my local machine: https://colab.research.google.com/github/Curt-Park/rainbow-is-all-you-need/blob/master/08.rainbow.ipynb

```
C:/w/1/s/tmp_conda_3.6_045031/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1565412750030/work/aten/src/THC/THCTensorIndex.cu:189: block: [25,0,0], thread: [63,0,0] Assertion dstIndex < dstAddDimSize failed.
THCudaCheck FAIL file=C:/w/1/s/tmp_conda_3.6_045031/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1565412750030/work/aten/src\THC/THCTensorMathCompareT.cuh line=69 error=59 : device-side assert triggered
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “rainbow.py”, line 763, in
agent.train(epochs, horizon)
File “rainbow.py”, line 629, in train
loss = self.update_model()
File “rainbow.py”, line 578, in update_model
elementwise_loss_n_loss = self._compute_dqn_loss(samples, gamma)
File “rainbow.py”, line 710, in _compute_dqn_loss
dist = self.dqn.dist(state)
File “rainbow.py”, line 386, in dist
print(x)
File “C:\Users\un_po\Anaconda3\envs\rainbowPy\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py”, line 82, in repr
return torch._tensor_str._str(self)
File “C:\Users\un_po\Anaconda3\envs\rainbowPy\lib\site-packages\torch_tensor_str.py”, line 300, in _str
tensor_str = _tensor_str(self, indent)
File “C:\Users\un_po\Anaconda3\envs\rainbowPy\lib\site-packages\torch_tensor_str.py”, line 201, in _tensor_str
formatter = _Formatter(get_summarized_data(self) if summarize else self)
File “C:\Users\un_po\Anaconda3\envs\rainbowPy\lib\site-packages\torch_tensor_str.py”, line 87, in init
nonzero_finite_vals = torch.masked_select(tensor_view, torch.isfinite(tensor_view) & tensor_view.ne(0))
File “C:\Users\un_po\Anaconda3\envs\rainbowPy\lib\site-packages\torch\functional.py”, line 228, in isfinite
return (tensor == tensor) & (tensor.abs() != inf)
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (59) : device-side assert triggered at C:/w/1/s/tmp_conda_3.6_045031/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1565412750030/work/aten/src\THC/THCTensorMathCompareT.cuh:69
```

Yesterday the same code just worked fine.

And the code still works on CPU.

Comment: Downgrading pytorch and cuda helped...

Comment: I guess you tried a reboot or maybe a system update first?

Comment: Yes I have tried driver reinstallations etc. . I also get some recommendations on github, but so far I had no success. In october I will have more time to investigate the root cause.

Comment: Did you try [anomaly detection](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#anomaly-detection). I'm also getting unexpected GPU errors, but solved it by running that particular calculation in numpy (on CPU of course). This was ok in my case as it runs just once and I waiting a few hours isn't a big issue.